# Run tests without focus on newly created session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

While I'm running protractor tests, each scenario creates new session, opens new Chrome window and changes focus on that window.

I'm looking for solution which either won't focus on newly created session, or will run all tests in background.

The tricky part is:

- I'm using `directConnect: true` flag
- in hooks in AfterScenario `browser.restart()` is invoked

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you want to run all your tests in a single chrome browser?

Comment: yes, indeed - there's no need to run tests in parallel